# Desperately trying to figure out how to display API info on HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

Im trying to figure out a way to display crypto currency prices in real time on my website. So far Ive got a script that works at posting the current price but im having trouble using the setinterval to autorefresh the data. This is the code im using, and I think ive lost it at the setinterval part, please help!!!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Site</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #data {
        text-align: center;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
        
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4  &&  this.status == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                parseJson(json);
            }       
        };
        
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        
        function parseJson(json) {
            var usdValue = "Bitcoin Price: $" + json["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"];
            
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
                usdValue;
        }

setInterval(data, 3000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your a bit please have a look it will work for you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Site</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #data {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadBitCointPrice(){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
            
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4  &&  this.status == 200) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    parseJson(json);
                }       
            };
            
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        
        
        function parseJson(json) {
            var usdValue = "Bitcoin Price: $" + json["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"];
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = usdValue;
        }

    setInterval(function(){
        loadBitCointPrice();
    }, 3000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the code that pulls the data in a function, and then use `setInterval` to call that function:

```js
function pullData() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      parseJson(json);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  function parseJson(json) {
    var usdValue = "Bitcoin Price: $" + json["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"];

    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
      usdValue;

    console.log('Data updated at', new Date())
  }
}

pullData() // Call it immediately the first time.
setInterval(pullData, 3000);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Site</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #data {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="data" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think im in way over my head here, I dont even know where to put those two pieces of code.